# Como puedo montar una matriz personalizada?

Tags: python, matrices, powerbi

Estoy intentando montar una matriz en Power BI Desktop, pero o no puedo o no sé como hacerlo, os explico lo que busco:

Tengo 5 columnas en mi tabla, 3 de ellas son categorias, 1 son valores y la ultima son fechas. Lo que quiero tener es una matriz que me permita poner las 3 columnas de categorias sin una ordenacion jerarquica, una al lado de la otra. Intento pintar a lo que me refiero:

```
TENGO ESTO
              2019-10      2019-11      2019-12 
X
 Y   
  Z             40           45           57
X
 Y
  Z             41           50           1
X
 Y 
  Z             40           45           57
```

---

```
O ESTO
              2019-10      2019-11      2019-12 
X - Y - Z        40           45           57
X - Y - Z        41           50           1
X - Y - Z        40           45           57
```

---

```
QUIERO ESTO
              2019-10      2019-11      2019-12 
X   Y   Z        40           45           57
X   Y   Z        41           50           1
X   Y   Z        40           45           57
```

Si pongo las 3 columnas de categorias en la seccion de filas, se ordenan jerarquicamente, o bien si cojo esas 3 columnas y las concateno en una nueva ya solo tengo un campo, el problema de esto ultimo es que al tener los campos de esas columnas una longitud distinta entre ellos quedan desalineados, y lo que me gustaria tener es todo alineado.

Es posible hacerlo de alguna manera?

Gracias.

Comment: Puedes mostrar el codigo que tienes con la generacion de la tabla?

Comment: Incluye el código necesario para replicar el problema por favor, así como está no es claro como ayudarte.

Comment: No hay ningun código, estoy usando simplemente las herramientas de PowerBI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado como hacerlo.

En el panel de Visualizaciones->Formato->Encabezados de fila->Diseño escalonado->Off